# MVC PartialView page rendering dropdown value and checkboxes

Tags: datatables, partial-views, html.dropdownlistfor, asp.net-mvc-areas, asp.net-mvc-5

I am working on an mvc page, it has 2 partial views and one controller action. In one of the partial views i have a button, this button checks if the user entry exists in the database. in the other partial view i have a drop down and a table, the table is populated based on the dropdown selection.

My issue is, everytime I select some values in the table( all are check boxes) then enter some values for "Verify" button the form refreshes and clears out all selected checkboxes. is there a way to fix this?

P.S.:
I am using Viewbag to bind to dropdown selection and onchange event for dropdown. 
Please guide me in fixing this. this is driving me insane.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If I undestand you as correctly, You can use javascript I think :). Also If you dont want to load all page, you can look **ajax post with partial View in MVC**

This may help your problem :D